# How to provide image as a fake Camera frame in UI testing with CameraX?

Tags: android, testing, android-testing, android-camera2, android-camerax

I'm using CameraX in my application having image analysis + preview use case. I want to write a UI test (Espresso or UI Automator) by which I can inject a fake image as a source of the Camera and want to verify the output accordingly. How can I inject a fake image as a source in such a way that it'll be visible in Surface's preview and the same will be available as `ImageProxy` in image analysis?